# Show different JSON objects inside loop of other object in Handlebars for a condtition

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I am rendering two different objects from JS file to HBS file. Let these objects be Obj1 and Obj2. On the HBS file, I am looping Obj1 in a table. But at some row of the table, I want to access Obj2. I am not able to access that.

**home.hbs**

```
<tbody>
    {{#Obj1}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>            //From Obj1 (Working Fine)
        <td>{{Place}}</td>          //From Obj1  (Working Fine)
        <td>{{Obj2.Country}}</td>  //Here I want to access value from Obj2 if Obj1.Name==Obj2.Name
    </tr>
    {{/Obj1}}
</tbody>
```

***JS***

```
res.render('home',{
   Obj1: personData;
   Obj2: countryData;
})
```

***Objects***

Obj1=[{Name: John, Place: New York},{Name: Raman, Place: New Delhi}]

Obj2=[{Name: John, Country: USA},{Name: Raman, Country: India}]

Comment: Please share how obj1 and obj2 look like.

Comment: Obj1=[{Name: John, Place: New York},{Name: Raman, Place: New Delhi}]
Obj2=[{Name: John, Country: USA},{Name: Raman, Country: India}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if it is at all possible, I would advise you to alter your data structure. Since it is clear from the sample arrays you provided, the data in each array (`Obj1` and `Obj2`) are strongly related. It makes much more sense to have a single array with objects like:

```
{
  "Name": "John",
  "Place": "New York",
  "Country": "USA"
}
```

than it does to split the Place and Country across objects in separate arrays, linked by the array index.

Aside: I would also recommend renaming these variables - "Obj1" and "Obj2" - because they are arrays, which is more specific than object.

However, if you absolutely must use the two arrays, it is possible to get a property from one array while iterating through the other with the use of a [context path](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context), the [lookup helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup), and the [@index data-variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index).

What we want to do is: inside our loop of the array `Ojb1`, get object from the array `Obj2` at the corresponding iteration index and get its `Country` property.

Handlebars provides a convenience data variable, `@index`, which can be used within a loop to get the current iteration index. We can use this to lookup the object in `Obj2` at the same index: `lookup ../Obj2 @index`. Note that we must prefix `Obj2` with `../` which tells Handlebars that we must step up a single context level to where `Obj1` and `Obj2` live. Once we have that object, we can use a second lookup to get its `Country` property.

The full code becomes:

```
{{lookup (lookup ../Obj2 @index) 'Country'}}
```

The parentheses are necessary because the nested lookup is a [subexpression](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions).

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/64v1jf7x/) for your reference.

Comment: Thank You so much. This pretty much helped a lot. I used these objects just as a reference to my actual problem. May I know how can I do this for different sized objects. Like 

Obj1=[{Name: John, Place: New York},{Name: Raman, Place: New Delhi}]

Obj2=[{Name: John, Country: USA},{Name: Mark, Country: India}, {Name: Raman, Country: India}]

I want to match data for Raman.

Comment: @UtkrishtAgrawal: That is more complicated. You would need to use a custom helper to search through the second array for a matching name - like: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/3st5ko2d/ . Truthfully, the best and correct course of action is to change your data structure; the logic you will need is not suited for being performed in a template.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `Obj2` is an `Array` and it has no property `Country`.
So, you can do `Obj2[<index>].Country` such as `Obj2[0].Country`

#### EDIT: You can loop through two objects like this is your view.

```js
var Obj2 = [{Name: "John", Country: "USA"},{Name: "Raman", Country: "India"}];
var Obj1 = [{Name: "John", Place: "New York"},{Name: "Raman", Place: "New Delhi"}];

Obj2.forEach((e, i) => {
    console.log(e, Obj1[i]);
})
```

Comment: Since I am looping through Obj1 in HBS I am not able to access Obj2 inside Obj1. How can I do that?