# Access context variable from different scope in each loop handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, express, handlebars.js, jsforce

I'm quite new to handlebars, and I'm wondering if I can access other objects field values inside an each loop created using another object. This is what I'm currently trying to do, I get no value on the table cell that I'm trying to set {{../entry/UnitPrice}} on the value.

JavaScript code:

```
context = {
        prod : prodResult.records,
        entry : entryResult.records,
        ts : prodResult.totalSize
      }
      res.render('prodlist', context)
```

Handlebars code:

```
<h1>DONE</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
    </tr>
    {{#each prod}}
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" value="{{Id}}"></td>
        <td>{{Name}}</td>
        <td>{{../entry.UnitPrice}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `entryResults.records` look liike?

Comment: The code you have shared will work just fine assuming that `context.entry` is an object with a `UnitPrice` property, like `{ "UnitPrice": "49.99" }`. However, since you are referencing it in a loop, I am left to guess that it is an array, in which case you would need to lookup an element at a particular index. If this is the case, this post may be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69014693/3397771

Comment: Thanks, that was just the problem that I was having, later ill write the answer to the post, so other people can benefit from your answer @76484